# Use implicit differentiation to find dy/dx for $x \ge -2$. $y\sqrt{x+2}=xy+3$; I am getting a different answer than is given

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

$$y\sqrt{x+2}=xy+3$$ find $\frac {dy}{dx}$ for $x \ge -2$.

The given answer is $$-\frac{y(2(x+2)^{1/2}-1)}{2(x(x+2)^{1/2}-x-2)}$$

Here's my work so far:

$$y\sqrt{x+2}=xy+3$$
$$y\frac d{dx}\sqrt{x+2}+\frac{dy}{dx}\sqrt{x+2}=y\frac d{dx}x+\frac{dy}{dx}x+0$$
$$y\cdot\frac12(x+2)^{-1/2}+\frac{dy}{dx}(x+2)^{1/2}=y\cdot1+\frac{dy}{dx}x+0$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}(x+2)^{1/2}-\frac{dy}{dx}x=-y\cdot\frac12(x+2)^{-1/2}+y$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\left((x+2)^{1/2}-x\right)=-\frac12y(x+2)^{-1/2}+y$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-\frac12y(x+2)^{-1/2}+y}{(x+2)^{1/2}-x}$$

Please be kind; it is my first time posting here and I'm still in highschool. I'm just having trouble figuring out where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please let us know what you have tried so that we can better help you.

Comment: To elaborate a bit, this should be a fairly easy problem with implicit differentiation (and even with regular differentiation), so it's not clear to us where you're having difficulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no mistake in your work, and your final "$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-\frac12y(x+2)^{-1/2}+y}{(x+2)^{1/2}-x}$" was very close to the "given answer $-\frac{y(2(x+2)^{1/2}-1)}{2(x(x+2)^{1/2}-x-2)}$" you are reporting:
$$\begin{align}\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{-\frac12y(x+2)^{-1/2}+y}{(x+2)^{1/2}-x}\\
&=-\frac{\left(y-\frac12y(x+2)^{-1/2}\right)2(x+2)^{1/2}}{\left(x-(x+2)^{1/2}\right)2(x+2)^{1/2}}\\&=-\frac{y\left(2(x+2)^{1/2}-1\right)}{2\left(x(x+2)^{1/2}-x-2\right)}.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Given $$y\sqrt{x+2} - xy = 3$$

Let us factor out a $y$ on the left hand side, then divide by the parenthetical term:

$$y = \frac{3}{\sqrt{x+2} - x}$$

Now, we are prepared to take the derivative with respect to $x$. This can be done e.g. using the quotient rule or product rule, along with the chain rule.

As to implicit differentiation, you could start by taking the derivative of both sides of your given equation:

$$y \cdot \frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{x+2} + \frac{dy}{dx} \cdot \sqrt{x+2} = y \cdot \frac{d}{dx}x + \frac{dy}{dx} x + 0$$

I did not write out any of the actual differentiation, since it is not clear where your troubles lie. For example, in the preceding equation, the term $\frac{d}{dx}x$ would simply be $1$. Without further context, it's unclear where you're running into trouble.

If you pursue the latter equation, you should eventually be able to rearrange so as to solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in terms of $x$ alone; if done correctly, you will know because it will match up with the derivative found using the first method (standard differentiation).

Comment: Thanks, when I follow your notes for solving using implicit differentiation, this is what I get. Could you shed some light on where I’m going wrong? [My work](https://ibb.co/0K6KNKh)

Comment: @ilya.te Factor out a $y$ in the final expression that you have, and then substitute the value of $y$ in terms of $x$ (which is included in my response above) so that your final answer for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ contains only the variable $x$ in it...

Comment: This answer does not adress the OP's problem "I'm just having trouble figuring out where I'm going wrong here." Actually, [the answer is: "Nowhere!"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4727427).

Comment: @AnneBauval The quoted portion that you include was not included when I posted my response. Even still, for the part written down, it would be ideal imo to replace the $y$ with an expression solely in terms of $x$; which, in the case of this problem, is doable. $$ $$My answer addressed that which was posted at the time.